# MongoDB ISODate field search using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, isodate

I am having trouble searching ISODate field in mongodb using Java. I want to find exact matched date.

Here's how I query first collection and get ISODate field "Timestamp". Once I get this date, I want to search another collection with the same "Timestamp" value.

```
    FindIterable<Document> docList = thermalComfortCollection.find();
    for(Document doc: docList) {

        String ts = doc.get("Timestamp").toString();
        System.out.println(ts);
```

...

I am formatting ISODate since it returns me date in a different format that I would like to search. Therefore, I am converting it into this pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

```
        final DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = 
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

        // The parsed date
        final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(ts, inputFormat);

        // The output format
        final DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String date = outputFormat.format(parsed);
```

I could not find how to write exact match statement for ISODate type, so I am putting both gte and lte conditions to get an exact match..!

```
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Timestamp", //
                          new BasicDBObject("$gte", date).append("$lte", date));
                System.out.println(query);
```

And the query is not working. Could you give me any comment which part of my code is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Since MongoDB saves all dates in UTC with the timezone, you'll need to query on a `Date` instance with timezone set as UTC.

Let's day this is my document in MongoDB

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58886fa477717752e6eff16b"), "dd" : ISODate("2017-01-25T09:28:04.041Z") }
```

To query it from Java, I'll do:

```
String dateStr = "2017-01-25 09:28:04.041 UTC";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ").parse(dateStr);
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("dd", date);
coll.find(filter);
```

Comment: Thank you! I found a problem in my code, it was because I did not correctly put filter with date.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the dates not their string formats.

For example, to compare on below timestamp.

```
{ "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-25T09:28:04.041Z") }
```

Code:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-01-25T09:28:04.041Z"); //Pass your date.

Date timestamp = Date.from(instant);
```

Query:

```
Document query = Filters.eq("timestamp", timestamp);
```

Comment: If I use this code, then it throws an error:  _java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Dec 21 05:45:00 PST 2016' could not be parsed at index 0_

Comment: Are you taking date as a string input ? Looks like your datetime has time zone. Parse to `ZonedDateTime - Instant - Date`

Comment: I initially put date as a string. It should be date structure, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-01-25T09:28:04.041Z"); // Pass your date.
Date timestamp = Date.from(instant);
Document query = Filters.eq("timestamp", timestamp);
```

Perfect solution if you are using Mongo Cursor from JAVA programming.