# Convert String Date(mm/dd/yyyy) to ISO format for MongoDB Query, Java

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime-format, iso8601, mongotemplate

how can we convert string with format mm/dd/yyyy to Date ISO format, which can be passed as an input to mongo db Query using java ?

eg: Input format for string is 11/30/2022 which needs to converted into ISODate("2022-11-30T00:00:00.000+0000")

**Update:**

Added the below code snippet which generated the date and passed to the query as shown in the below image and i'm using mongoTemplate to execute the query.

`mongoTemplate.find(query, Packet.class);`
[image]

When the codeis  executed it returns empty even though there is a record for the given input.

Ran this directly in mongodb client and it doesn't return anything.
[image]

But when I update the query to in mongodb client, by adding ISODate() it returns the correct response.
[image]

So wondering where i'm making a mistake!!

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("11/30/2022", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu")).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime()`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash If MongoDB doesn’t accept an `OffsetDateTime`, we may need to format it into a string without colon in the UTC offset.

Comment: Related (not the same, I think): [MongoDB ISODate field search using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847667/mongodb-isodate-field-search-using-java). Also without knowing MongoDB, this seems mighty helpful in my eyes: [Using Dates in CRUD Operations in MongoDB](https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-java-date-operations).

Comment: [*Using OffsetDateTime with Spring Boot and MongoDB*](https://bootify.io/mongodb/offset-date-time-with-spring-boot-mongodb.html)

Answer (score 3):

Parse the given date string into a `LocalDate` and then use [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) with `ZoneOffset.UTC` to convert it into an `OffsetDateTime`. Subsequently, format the obtained `OffsetDateTime` into the desired string.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
        OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDate.parse("11/30/2022", parser).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        String formatted = odt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"));
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-30T00:00Z
2022-11-30T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.